# How to insert | and || operators in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

In VB.NET, I can quickly type And/AndAlso on the keyboard. In C#, I'm currently opening Character Map and copying the 'OR' vertical line character manually. Am I missing something that allows quick insertion of the line symbol?

Comment: Do you not have a | character on your keyboard?

Comment: It's a key usually above the enter - `shift+\\`

Comment: What country are you in?  Keyboards vary.  And is it a full keyboard or a laptop?

Comment: You can type **and**, **or**
or use ascii alt + 38, 124

Comment: @arx more importantly, what's his keyboard layout setting.

Comment: @harold if the OP knew enough to use a non-standard layout I guessed he wouldn't have been asking the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is also called the `pipe` key, on many keyboards (UK/US) it is a single broken vertical line (one some keyboards it is a single unbroken vertical line, but I mostly see it as a broken one).

Image from [here](http://support.free-conversant.com/docs/resources).

[image: pipe key]

Comment: The broken and unbroken vertical lines are different characters.  My keyboard has both.  Only the unbroken line works as a pipe character.  However, some keys labelled with a broken line may actually return a pipe character.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you are from, but assume that you have a non-english keyboard. Unfortunately the C language (where this and other syntactic elements) originates from was developed with the english standard keyboard in mind.

I know some people here in Sweden are switching to english keyboard layout when coding - to get rid of the awkward placement of key C/C# characters like `| { [ ] } \`. (They are all combinations that require the `AltGr` key. Something had to be done to make place for the Swedish characters `ÅÄÖ` that all have their own keys.)

Comment: It's also worth noting that if your compiler supports ISO C trigraphs, then `??!` is equivalent to `|`. However `if (x ??!??! y) { ... }` is slightly less readable.

Comment: @Porges yes let's not do that please.

Comment: @Porges I was happily unaware of that alternative syntax. It looks horrible. I'm just on my way to bed and if I have nightmares about unreadable code it will be all your fault ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the keyboard layout, but the `|` / `pipe` should be somewhere on the left of the enter key (US layout), or on the left of `Z` or `1` (first normal, the other with AltGr, UK layout).

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you have the PIPE key, you could type, on the numeric keypad and keeping the ALT key pressed, the number 124

Comment: +1, but note that this only works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have the "pipe" symbol as <kbd>altGr</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>